# Socket.io Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Tags: javascript, socket.io

A particular event doesn’t work in my program where I am using socket.io. The rest works fine. This is where the problem occurs:

First html file:

```
 socket.on('connect', () => {socket.emit('phone', 'phone');});
```

Server file:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){ 
   io.on('phone', function(socket, data){ 
      io.emit('stuurbedrijfsnaam', 'stuurbedrijfsnaam'); 
   }); 
});
```

2nd html file:

```
socket.on('stuurbedrijfsnaam', function(socket){
    socket.emit('stuurbedrijfsnaam',bedrijfsnaam) 
})
```

This is the full error given in the console:

```
index.js:83 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
at r.emit (index.js:83)
at r.onevent (index.js:83)
at r.onpacket (index.js:83)
at r.<anonymous> (index.js:83)
at r.emit (index.js:83)
at r.ondecoded (index.js:83)
at a.<anonymous> (index.js:83)
at a.r.emit (index.js:83)
at a.add (index.js:83)
at r.ondata (index.js:83)
at r.<anonymous> (index.js:83)
at r.emit (index.js:83)
at r.onPacket (index.js:83)
at r.<anonymous> (index.js:83)
at r.emit (index.js:83)
at r.onPacket (index.js:83)
at r.onData (index.js:83)
at WebSocket.ws.onmessage (index.js:83)
```

It references index.js:83, which is inside a folder made by socket.io itself. There are lines 81, 82 and 83:

```
Backoff.prototype.setJitter = function(jitter){
    this.jitter = jitter;
    };
```

Hope I gave enough resources. It would be cool if someone’s help me out. Thanks!

Comment: We don't see all your code - please post all the code you are using so we can help fix your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of this error is that you're trying to call `.emit()` via the `socket` argument of your custom event handlers, [which is incorrect usage](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#socket-on-eventName-callback) according to the documentation for socket.io client side API.

Consider revising your client side code as follows by removing the `socket` argument from your handlers to cause `.emit()` to be called on the actual socket instance:

```
socket.on('stuurbedrijfsnaam', function(){ // remove 'socket' here

   // cause emit() to be called on actual socket instance
   socket.emit('stuurbedrijfsnaam',bedrijfsnaam) 
})
```

The reason `socket.emit('phone', 'phone');` in your first html file is that `emit()` is called on the original socket instance, rather than via a `socket` argument passed to the event handler, as you are doing in your seconds html file.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Does not work, unfortunately. Apparently, the arguments were not the problem. But thanks a lot for the extended answer!

Answer (score 3):

For Anybody Searching for this error. It can be caused by providing variable as a second parameter in `.on` method that is undefined. Internal code of socket.io tries to call `.apply` method to pass arguments into your event handler. If function registered is not existing and therefore `undefined`, this error occurs since undefined values have no such property .  It often may be the case of the typo in the name of the function

i.e

```
socket.on('next_player', this.nextplayer)
```

should be :

```
socket.on('next_player', this.next_player)
```