# Socket.io TypeError: Cannot read property 'hteam' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I am new to Socket and I am using it to get live Australian football scores from [this API](https://api.squiggle.com.au/) and displaying them with Express/Pug.

I can get them to display in the browser fine but in the console I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hteam' of undefined
    at r.<anonymous> (round2:8)
    at r.emit (index.js:83)
    at r.onevent (index.js:83)
    at r.onpacket (index.js:83)
    at r.<anonymous> (index.js:83)
    at r.emit (index.js:83)
    at r.ondecoded (index.js:83)
    at a.<anonymous> (index.js:83)
    at a.r.emit (index.js:83)
    at a.add (index.js:83)
```

I have tried the solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659864/socket-io-typeerror-cannot-read-property-emit-of-undefined) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53311432/socket-io-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-apply-of-undefined) but none of them work.

My **index.js** file is:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
exports.io = require('socket.io')(http);
const path = require('path');
const routes = require('./routes/routes');
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use('/', routes);

http.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:' + port);
  });
```

My **routes.js** file is:

```
onst express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();
const controllers = require('../controllers/controllers');

router.get('/round1', controllers.getRound1);
router.get('/round2', controllers.getRound2);
router.get('/round3', controllers.getRound3);

module.exports = router;
```

My **controller.js** file is:

```
var http = require('http').createServer(require('express')());
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
const got = require('got');
var { io } = require('../index');
let interval;

const getApiAndEmit = async (socket, round) => {
    try {
      const response = await got('https://api.squiggle.com.au/?q=games');
      const parsed = JSON.parse(response.body);
      gamesArray = parsed.games;
      const roundArray = [];
      gamesArray.forEach(element => {
          if (element.round === round && element.year === 2020) {
              roundArray.push(element); 
          }
      });
      socket.emit('FromAPI', roundArray);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Error: ${error.code}`);
    }
};

let getGame = function (round) {
    io.on('connect', socket => {
        if (interval) {
          clearInterval(interval);
        }
        interval = setInterval(() => getApiAndEmit(socket, round), 3000);
    }); 
}



exports.getRound1 = function (req, res) {
    getGame(1);
    res.render('game', {title: 1});
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
};

exports.getRound2 = function (req, res) {
    getGame(2);
    res.render('game', {title: 2});
};

exports.getRound3 = function (req, res) {
    getGame(3);
    res.render('game', {title: 3});
};
```

My Pug **view** is:

```
block layout-content
    h1 Round #{title}
    p(id='score')
        p(class='game')
        p(class='game')
        p(class='game')
        p(class='game')
        p(class='game')
        p(class='game')
        p(class='game')
        p(class='game')
        p(class='game')

    script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")
    script.
        const scores = document.getElementById('scores');
        const games = document.getElementsByClassName('game');
        const socket = io();

        socket.on('FromAPI', roundArray => {

            for (let i = 0; i < games.length; i++) {
                games[i].innerHTML= ` ${roundArray[i].hteam} ${roundArray[i].hgoals}.${roundArray[i].hbehinds} ${roundArray[i].hscore} v ${roundArray[i].ateam} ${roundArray[i].ascore}`
            }
        });
```

My **package.json** is:

```
{
    "name": "socket afl scores",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "my first socket.io app",
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "got": "^11.3.0",
        "pug": "^3.0.0",
        "socket.io": "^2.3.0"
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: In your controller for round1, you're sending back a rendered view and a static file (index.html). You'll probably want to remove one of these. As for the error, try inserting a `console.log(roundArray)` in your `FromAPI` handler. (Also, depending on what else you're planning to do in this app, you might want to run the interval on the client instead, and simply fetch() current data) (also also, I'm running your code without issues)

Comment: Thanks. `console.log` helped me pinpoint the source of the error. Also, good idea on the interval. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the error was on the client side in **view**.

The conditional statement of the for loop should have been

```
(let i = 0; i < roundArray.length; i++)
```

Comment: Ah, I missed that. There's no need to post answers for errors such as this; even if somebody made the same type of error, they'd never find this question.